# Set individual timeout for each arrival in simmer R

Tags: r, simulation, traffic

In simmer, is it possible to assign an individual timeout for each arrival (at the same point in time)?

I am developing a discrete event simulation of vehicles travelling along road segments.  The travel time on each road segment is a function of how many vehicles are already on the segment. For earlier vehicles, travel times should be at free flow speeds, and only later vehicles should be impacted by congestion.

With the example code below, my problem is that the activity time for vehicle0 is at the congested speed (120kph), when it should be at free-flow speed (60kph).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(simmer)
library(simmer.plot)
library(simmer.bricks)

rm(list = ls())


# Globals ----
limit_freeflow_segment1 <- 20 # Max vehicles (before congestion)
limit_segment1 <- limit_freeflow_segment1 * 2 # Max vehicles
freeflow_speed_segment1 <- 60 # Free flow speed
kms_segment1 <- 60 # Length of road segment (kms)

# Monitor object to collect results ----
mon <- monitor_csv()

road_sim <-
    simmer(mon = mon)

# Timeout functions ----
mins_segment1 <- function(vehicles) {
    if (vehicles < limit_freeflow_segment1) {
        speed <- freeflow_speed_segment1
    } else {
        speed <- (limit_freeflow_segment1 / vehicles) * freeflow_speed_segment1
    }
    mins <- kms_segment1 / speed * 60
    return(mins)
}

# Trajectory ----
vehicle_traj <- trajectory() %>%
    # Road segment 1 ----
    seize("road_segment_1") %>%
    set_global(
        "vehicles_on_segment_1",
        function() get_server_count(.env = road_sim, resources = "road_segment_1")
    ) %>%
    set_global(
        "travel_mins",
        function() mins_segment1(vehicles = get_server_count(.env = road_sim, resources = "road_segment_1"))
    ) %>%
    # Travel mins should be a function of how many vehicles are already on the segment.
    timeout(
        function() mins_segment1(vehicles = get_server_count(.env = road_sim, resources = "road_segment_1"))
    ) %>%
    release("road_segment_1")

road_sim %>%
    add_generator(
        name_prefix = "vehicle",
        trajectory = vehicle_traj,
        distribution <- at(sort(rep(1:1, 100))) # 1) tranches 2) n per tranche
    ) %>%
    add_resource(name = "road_segment_1", capacity = limit_segment1) %>%
    run()

# Get results ----
arrivals <- road_sim %>%
    get_mon_arrivals()

resources <- road_sim %>%
    get_mon_resources()

attributes <- road_sim %>%
    get_mon_attributes()

View(arrivals)
```

Answer (score 0):

All your vehicles arrive at the same time, `t=1`, so you have an issue of simultaneous arrivals there. If you randomize your arrivals, or just provide a vector like `distribution=at(1:100)`, then the issue disappears. On the other hand, are you setting a velocity value as a timeout?